# How to place Chromedriver on the path when developing in the cloud? Trying to use Watir in RoR while developing on c9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, c9.io

I'm using a Chrome browser, but the error I'm getting is

"Unable to find chromedriver. Please download the server from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and place it somewhere on your PATH. More info at https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver."

I'm not sure where to place it on the path when developing in the **cloud**.  Any help is much appreciated.

Here is the code in my controller

```
def getinformation
    require 'watir'

    browser = Watir::Browser.new

    browser.goto('http://stackoverflow.com/')

    @broswer = browser.title

end
```

Comment: You are using `watir` in your actual application, not just for testing?

Comment: Yeah, I want to use it to webscrape.

Comment: `nokogiri` will do a much better job as a page scraper and if you need `js` functionality `watir` and `phantomjs` rather than a full chrome driver is probably a better bet.

Comment: Could you perhaps explain what watir, and what phantomjs do and how they work together?

Comment: [`phantomjs`](http://phantomjs.org/) is a headless webkit that is fully js scriptable. `ghostdriver` is an integrated web driver as of phantomjs 1.8 and provides the web driver functionality needed by watir. `nokogiri` will provide the page parsing as needed. [PhantomJs Ruby example using selenium](http://phantomjs.org/release-1.8.html) (maybe this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QK_uRnS5cT8) will help as well). using `npm` (should be available on cloud 9) one can install phantomjs using `npm i -g phantomjs-prebuilt` the `-g` makes it global

Comment: you can run `echo $PATH` in bash to see all the folders, but a safe bet would be /usr/bin or /usr/local/sbin